# Pull up is not available on this type. All super types are binary

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, refactoring

I am doing lots of refactoring of a **large** Java project in Eclipse (Juno).

When I open the context menu and Refactor > Pull up... on a certain method I wish to move to the super class, I get the following notification:

> Pull up is not available on this type.  All super types are binary.

I am fairly certain this is because the superclass is imported from another package currently compiled in my project as a jar.  I can edit this jar of course and recompile, so the issue is not that I do not have access to the source, but that Eclipse will not find the source in the other package.

So my question:

*Are there any workarounds/solutions?*

What I have tried is to move the method(s) manually, but, of course, I do not want to do that, or else I would not be using Eclipse's refactoring capabilities in the first place.  On top of that, most methods I am moving are large methods with many other private method calls within them, so Eclipse does a nice job of finding those for me and moving them all at once.  The code base is very large and moving them manually became confusing and error prone very quickly.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments and answers given, it seems some clarification is needed.

One answer by Simon André Forsberg suggests adding the "jar" project to my java build path.  This is already done.  I still get the notification regardless.

One comment reads:

> OK. Tell us exactly **what** you wish Eclipse do for you and give us a hint **how** Eclipse can reliably do that based on available information. –  PM 77-1

1. I wish for Eclipse to display the `pull up...` refactoring wizard, as opposed to the notification "Pull up is not available on this type. All super types are binary."
2. I do not know how Eclipse can reliably do that.  That is why I posted this question.

Comment: Why do you think that your `jar` includes source code?

Comment: @PM77-1 What I mean is I can perform this function in subclasses of the super that are within the same package.  I cannot do it for subclasses that are within a different package.  For the subclasses within a different a package, they reference the super via a compiled jar.  Does that make sense?

Comment: OK. Tell us exactly **what** you wish Eclipse do for you and give us a hint **how** Eclipse can reliably do that based on available information.

Comment: @PM77-1 Please see my edit to the post.

Comment: How can Eclipse guess **where** to look for the source code of your superclass?

Comment: @PM77-1 To answer your question specifically, I don't know, which is why I asked the question.  Perhaps it is a very elementary question.  Truth is, I did not know, so I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because that **you** have the ability to recompile your project and export another JAR, doesn't mean that **Eclipse** knows that you are able to do that.

If the other package is available in your workspace, then you could add **the project** to your build path, instead of first compiling it to a jar. If Eclipse knows that you want to use code from another project in your workspace, then it will know how to find and manipulate the source of that project as well.

What you should do is to **Add the project to your build path and exclude the JAR-file**

This screenshot is showing where to add another project to your build path, taken from the Eclipse wiki:

[image: Eclipse dialog for adding project to build path]

Comment: I already have the project added to my build path.  I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Then why on earth have you included the package as a JAR?

Comment: This project has gone through many changes.  The project is in the build path because of some change made days or weeks ago.  It is probably no longer necessary, but I am unsure at this point.  Regardless, whether or not it is added to the build path makes no difference.  I have tried it either way, I still get the notification.

Comment: To answer your question more specifically, it is included as a jar because Maven builds the projects when we push to dev, and that is how all the project references are resolved.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Have you tried adding the project to the build path and **excluding** the JAR?

Comment: I cannot exclude the jar because we do Maven builds that create the jars and add them as dependencies to various projects.  It would break the entire system.  (I will still try to see if this works, but it cannot be the final solution).

Comment: Ah.  That was it.  The Maven variable that included the jar was removed, and I added the project via the buildpath from my workspace.  And it works.  Thank you.  What I will have to do is remove the Maven variable from the build path, add my workspace project to the build path, do my refactoring, and then remove workspace project from build path, and re-add maven variable to build path.  It looks like I will have to redo and undo some actions if I want to use the refactor wizard in this case :/

Comment: If you can revise your answer somehow to reflect this (if possible), I will accept it as the solution, otherwise I will post my own solution.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Added a line to my answer with instruction to remove the JAR from the build path. Is that satisfactory or where you looking for another change in my answer?

Comment: Yes that is satisfactory, Thank you.